# Sourcemap for file.mjs points to missing source file in Vite.js React app with a module

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite

I've installed a custom JS library with pnpm add that looks like this in package.json:

`"examplename": "link:..\\relative-path-to-the-library",`

The package.json of the library in the node_modules looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "examplename",
  "version": "0.0.0-unspecified",
  "main": "examplename.mjs",
  "types": "examplename.d.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.21",
    "webpack": "5.82.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "4.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.15.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "2.6.7",
    "abort-controller": "3.0.0",
    "ws": "8.5.0",
    "format-util": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "bundledDependencies": []
}
```

Next to the package.json file, in node_modules there are also files:

```
examplename.d.t.s
examplename.mjs
examplename.mjs.map
```

The mjs file is 4MB, map is 1,5MB.

The mjs file contains at the end:

`//# sourceMappingURL=examplename.mjs.map`

So the module contains a mjs file that is the main file indicated in package.json, and that mjs file contains a source map URL pointing to the examplename.mjs.map that is just next to it.

But when I run my React app that contains the dependency to the examplename module with the vite command I get this error in the terminal:

`Sourcemap for "C:/absolute-path-to-the-library/examplename.mjs" points to missing source files`

The error shouldn't occur and Vite should recognize there is actually a sourcemap.

How to make Vite recognize that there's a source map?